# Shelf Stable Cream Cheese or Sub Cream Cheese Frosting?

Tags: baking, cream-cheese

I am attempting to get licensure to make Cottage Food and I make a delicious guava and cream cheese pastelito. However, cream cheese is a prohibited food ingredient due to its need to be refrigerated. My question is, is there a way to make cream cheese shelf stable or an alternative or can I get away with substituting cream cheese frosting (like a grocery store bought Pillsbury)?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  To answer your question, folks will need to know what country/province's food regulations you're working under.